# I want to place UIView upon keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

When the keyboard is shown, I want to measure the keyboard's height and place a view upon it.
In the code below, the view is raised but it's deviated.

Process:

1. Create View
2. Set constraint (isHidden = true)
3. Get keyboard's height
4. Update constraint(isHidden = false)

Code:

```
class CompanyDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var applyView: ApplyView!
    private var applyViewBottom: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create view and set constraint
        self.applyView = UINib(nibName: "ApplyView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! ApplyView
        view.addSubview(self.applyView)
        self.applyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.applyView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 204)
        self.applyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.applyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        let applyViewBotttom = self.applyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        applyViewBotttom.isActive = true
        self.applyViewBottom = applyViewBotttom
        addNotification()
    }

    private func addNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: .UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: Any] else {
            return
        }
        guard let keyboardInfo = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return
        }
        guard let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {
            return
        }
        // Get keyboard's height and update constraint
        self.applyView.isHidden = false
        self.applyViewBottom?.constant = -keyboardInfo.cgSizeValue.height
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has a HUGE chance to be refused by Apple review. Are you trying to replace the original keyboard ? If so, there are several ways to do it. And the way you're trying is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@objc func keyboardWillShowNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {

        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue

        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow

        applyViewBotttom.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

[Demo example](https://github.com/paresh1994/KeyboardEx)

Comment: please download demo example from link and check